# Nodejs crash: GC segfault

Tags: node.js, linux, express, sails.js

- **Node version**: 4.8.0
- **Platform**: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Node crashed during the Garbace collection but without any other high level pattern (maybe related to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3715).

Unfurtunately I don't have any code to reproduce as I was not able to isolate the problem.

This is the crash stack trace captured with segfault-handler module:

```
PID 24495 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x3809f3d021f8
<path_node_modules>/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x1a5b)[0x7f7dd565ca5b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890)[0x7f7dd9c20890]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal20MarkCompactCollector22ProcessWeakCollectionsEv+0xfd)[0xaec4dd]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal20MarkCompactCollector15MarkLiveObjectsEv+0x214)[0xaf3a14]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal20MarkCompactCollector14CollectGarbageEv+0x11)[0xaf47e1]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap11MarkCompactEv+0x60)[0xaaafe0]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap24PerformGarbageCollectionENS0_16GarbageCollectorENS_15GCCallbackFlagsE+0x4c0)[0xac2be0]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap14CollectGarbageENS0_16GarbageCollectorEPKcS4_NS_15GCCallbackFlagsE+0x238)[0xac30f8]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap15HandleGCRequestEv+0x8f)[0xac3aef]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal10StackGuard16HandleInterruptsEv+0x31c)[0xa6041c]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal18Runtime_StackGuardEiPPNS0_6ObjectEPNS0_7IsolateE+0x2b)[0xca51ab]
[0x2f2137d0963b]
```

And also this other stack sometimes:

```
PID 7545 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x68233500009
/home/documentapp/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x1a5b)[0x7f89249bfa5b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890)[0x7f8928f83890]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal32IncrementalMarkingMarkingVisitor26VisitFixedArrayIncrementalEPNS0_3MapEPNS0_10HeapObjectE+0x3fe)[0xad51ee]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal18IncrementalMarking4StepElNS1_16CompletionActionENS1_18ForceMarkingActionENS1_21ForceCompletionActionE+0x30c)[0xad2a7c]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal8NewSpace15SlowAllocateRawEiNS0_19AllocationAlignmentE+0x78)[0xb00f18]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap11AllocateRawEiNS0_15AllocationSpaceES2_NS0_19AllocationAlignmentE+0x109)[0xa64719]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal4Heap20AllocateFillerObjectEibNS0_15AllocationSpaceE+0x19)[0xaabd19]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal7Factory15NewFillerObjectEibNS0_15AllocationSpaceE+0x2d)[0xa64c5d]
/usr/bin/nodejs(_ZN2v88internal29Runtime_AllocateInTargetSpaceEiPPNS0_6ObjectEPNS0_7IsolateE+0x5e)[0xca52ee]
[0x1e31ede06355]
```

Can someone give me some hint on how I can find the prblem? Thanks

If you prefer you can also answer on the node issues that I have created:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11606

**Additional information:**
Node framework: express, Sails.js

My native modules founded with `find node_modules -name '*.node'` are:

```
node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node
node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node
node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/obj.target/segfault-handler.node
```

Comment: This is tagged as `C++`, yet I see no C++ code in the question.

Comment: The native modules are actually written in C++. And in many cases the segfault error is caused by them.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I removed the tag as actually can be misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be cause by mongodb logs that fill up the disk space a some point. Was actually hard to see because we clean this periodically so was not critical at the moment I've checked.